# GitlabCi - передача билда мужду runners

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-runner

Доброго времени суток.

Возник вопрос - Как передавать файл между бегунами gitlabCi.

Файл -  .gitlab-ci.yml

```
stages:
 - build
 - deploy
 - testing

build:win:
 stage: build
 script:
  - 'chcp 65001'
  - msbuild Test-project.sln
 artifacts:
  untracked: false
  paths:
   - Test-project\bin\Debug\Test-project.exe
  expire_in: 1 week
deploy:
 stage: deploy
 script: ?
```

Так вот, на стадии deploy, я хочу забрать получившийся арифакт из гитлаба, и поместить его на ранера. Как мне это сделать.

P.S.
 Пока рылся по документации, видел, что есть некая стабильная ссылка на последний собранный артифакт, но вот уже 3 день не могу на это наткнуться.
Всё происходит на виндовых машинах, кроме нахождения самого Gitlab.

Answer (score 1):

Никто не знает как, но я нашёл путь решения, механизм которого мне пока самому не понятен.

Суть такая:

```
deploy:
 stage: deploy
 tags:
  - linux
```

Тут нет никакого хитрого скрипта или прочего. Просто, после выполнения, бинарник оказался, на другой машине, где его, даже собрать возможности не было.

А для целей тестирования проекта, этого достаточно.